# why RecyclerView onDraw Delay

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want itemDecoration draw divider for only top three child. So, I return the onDraw in right time. But, I found that the itemDecoration onDraw() delayed. And Cause draw divider action delayed to recycle view sliding end.

here is my ItemDecoration onDraw() method:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = parent.getAdapter();
    if (adapter == null) {
        return;
    }

    int itemCount = adapter.getItemCount();
    int lastDividerOffset = getLastDividerOffset(parent);
    int validChildCount = parent.getChildCount();
    int lastChildPosition = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < validChildCount; i++) {
        //只给前三个child设置 divider
        View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
        int childAdapterPosition = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(child);
        if (childAdapterPosition >= 3) {
            return;
        }
```

getItemOffsets() method:

```
@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect rect, View v, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
        int childAdapterPosition = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(child);
        if (childAdapterPosition >= 3) {
            return;
        }
    }
    int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(v);
    int itemCount = parent.getAdapter().getItemCount();
    int lastDividerOffset = getLastDividerOffset(parent);
    if (!mShowLastDivider && position >= itemCount - lastDividerOffset) {
        // Don't set item offset for last line if mShowLastDivider = false
        return;
    }

    int groupIndex = getGroupIndex(position, parent);
    if (mVisibilityProvider.shouldHideDivider(groupIndex, parent)) {
        return;
    }

    setItemOffsets(rect, groupIndex, parent);
}
```

thanks.

Comment: what do you mean "delayed"?

Comment: recycle always show divider after sliding end. divider drawing may wait for 1 second.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Some xml's setting animation cause this problem.